# Starting a VBoxManage in Ubuntu on Startup

Tags: command-line, virtualbox, cron

I have a dedicated Ubuntu machine that is my daily driver.  I wanted to start using a virtualbox to load a windows ssd from an older computer.  I did the following from this website [https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/use-your-windows-10-instantly-inside-ubuntu-linux-from-pavic].

This works great and I can start and stop the VM.  One thing to note here is that I need to use
`sudo virtualbox`
to load the machine.  Using just the local virtualbox will not see the win10.vmdk file.  I think this is might be one of the main issues I am having.

My next task was to save the machine state of the VM with the following command:

```
VBoxManage controlvm <VMname> savestate
```

This works in both the cronjob and on the command line.  It saves the file machine state in this file: /root/VirtualBox VMs/VNname/VMname.vbox

If I am in the command line I can simply type in:

```
VBoxManage startvm VNname
```

And it starts the machine.  What does not work is when I try to do this from either a cronjob or a .sh job where I use the command line prompts.  I understand that this is the path to the saved state.

/root/VirtualBox VMs/VNname/VMname.vbox.

Any help in appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Click on 'menu', type startup in search box.
Click on app 'Startup Applications'.
Click button 'Add'.
Type the name of your command in first field.
Type the command you choose in second field.

```
virtualbox # GUI interface
# VBoxManage ... # what you need execute
```

For example
Type comment in third field, if needed.
Click button 'Add' on bottom side.